# How alert the default value for the table with out constraint value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to alert the default value for table that column without constraints.

Example:

```
  **ALTER Table [dbo].[Settings] ALTER column [Explore] bit set Default ((0))**
```

The above query I put to alter the column with default value false, but I run the query it show the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'" or "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Default'."

Comment: Did you mean to alter?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To add default constraint to an existing column you need to use this syntax

```
ALTER TABLE Settings ADD CONSTRAINT DF_name DEFAULT (0) FOR Explore;
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply if i remove the set keyword then it show the error like this "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Default'.

Answer (score 0):

**Here** is the way of achieving your requirement without constraint

Do the following if there isn't any data in the column

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Settings] DROP COLUMN Explore
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Settings] ADD Explore BIT DEFAULT 0
```

If you have data in the column and you want to preserve it then

1- Create column as `Explore_copy`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Settings] ADD Explore_copy BIT DEFAULT 0
```

2- Copy data from `Explore` to `Explore_copy`

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Settings] 
SET explore_copy = Explore
```

3- Drop old column `Explore`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Settings] DROP COLUMN Explore
```

4- Now, rename the `Explore_copy` to your original column name `Explore`

```
EXEC sp_RENAME '[dbo].[Settings].Explore_copy', 'Explore', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Shouldn’t step 2 be an `update` statement? The `insert` statement as it stands, would create new records where all columns other than `explore_copy` would be NULL, and then `dbo.Settings` will have 2n records. Its worth noting, this also assumes the `explore` column is in the last ordinal position.

Comment: Absolutely right, thank you very much. It's updated.